# Base change of a finite flat morphism has the same degree.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

1. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a finite flat morphism of degree $d$. Let $B\to Y$ be any morphism. It is well known that the base change $f_g\colon X\times_Y B\to B$ is a finite morhism. Is it true that the degree of $f_g$ is equal to $d$? I do not assume that $g$ is flat. We can assume that $X,Y,B$ are varities over a field of characteristic zero.
2. Is it true that $X\times_Y B$ is reduced, if I assume that $f,g$ are dominant? If it is not true what additional conditions I need to assume?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this follows from base change which works well when $f$ is flat without any assumption on $g$.
2. No, for instance take $B$ to be a point in the branch locus of $f$.

Comment: Does 2. become true if I assume $f,g$ to be dominant?

Comment: No. For instance, let $Y = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$, $X =  \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[u])$, $B =  \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[v])$ and consider the morphisms $f$ and $g$ given by $t \mapsto u^p$ and $t \mapsto v^p$, respectively. Then $X \times_Y B =  \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p[u,v]/(u^p - v^p))$ is not reduced.

Comment: I forgot to add that $X,Y, B$ are varieties over a field of characteristic zero. Is the statement true in this case?